# What's the minimum power level to destroy a planet?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

In [Buu saga](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Kid_Buu_Saga), Dragon Ball Z makes a huge deal of Kid Buu destroying the Earth, but Piccolo destroys the moon in the Vegeta Saga when his power level is sub 2000. Freeza destroying Namek is a whole affair, but Vegeta destroys Aria without breaking a sweat.

In DBZ, what is the minimum power level one must posses in order to destroy a planet?

Comment: I'm unable to track down the exact quote, but Akira Toriyama was quoted as saying power levels are intentionally irrelevant and unreliable in determining actual power or abilities. So it's not really possible to assign a hard power level required to destroy a planet... In terms of Piccolo destroying the moon, the moon is significantly smaller than Earth, so logically it would require less power.

Answer (score 1):

We can only go by what Vegeta says, at 18k, he says he is going to blow up the planet, we know however that Vegeta lies to bait his opponents.

We also know that if you have enough time you can concentrate your energy, so the answer would be less about power level and more about how much time you have vs your starting power level.